# Why do I get empty lists when listing files/folders in a folder using Sharepoint API?

Tags: sharepoint

I've just created a folder "import" in sharepoint, where I've created :

- 1 emtpy folder "testdir"
- 2 emtpy files "test1.csv" and "test2.csv".

When I query this "import" folder through API, I get a valid response but which contains an empty list ("value":[]) :

[https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/mypath/import')/Folders](https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/mysite/mypath/import%27)/Folders)

```
{"odata.metadata":"https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Folders1","value":[]}
```

[https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/mypath/import')/Files](https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/mysite/mypath/import%27)/Files)

```
{"odata.metadata":"https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Files12","value":[]}
```

What am I missing here ? Why can't I see my "testdir" folder and my 2 test.csv files ?

Would it be possible I have different permissions in API compared to web IHM ? (no directory listing permissions in API ?) for security reason ?

UPDATE : As an additional test, I tried this after creating an empty file in test dir :

[https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/mypath/import/testdir')/Files](https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/mysite/mypath/import/testdir%27)/Files)

And I get :

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024894, System.IO.FileNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"Fichier introuvable."}}}
```

What is happening here ? Is there a delay before I can query newly created folders/files ? Is there a "commit" command in sharepoint to create folder/files in sharepoint ?

UPDATE 2 :
If I use this syntax : "?$expand=Folders,Files",
I get (the non confidential part of the reponse) :
[image]

Using "%20" for all " " gives the exact same response.

Comment: Could it be that you have a typo in your folder path? For example, spaces are not encoded as %20 or something. Did you create the folders inside the default document library (called "Shared Documents") maybe and did not mention that in the path? If it was a permission issue, you would get "access denied".

Comment: Would it answer with a HTTP 200 if I had a typo though ? I dont know what "default document library (called "Shared Documents")" is, so no, it's created in an other directory.

Comment: Yes, it is HTTP 200 if there is a typo in the path (this on purpose). Try this: 
`https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/Shared%20Documents/folder')/Folders`. Note that after `mysite` you have `Shared%20Documents` and then your folder path. Or better, look at your address line when you open that folder in the browser.

Comment: Just to clarify the logic, in SharePoint you have this structure: sites > libraries > folders. You have folders in a document library, not on a site.

Comment: Ok, very interesting, I still dont know what "Shared%20Documents" is, but i'll try it on monday. Is is it a standard path in all sharepoints ?

Comment: No, it depends on the language. It may be "Freigegebene Dokumente" for a German site for example. The "shared documents" is default for an English team site. It depends on the site, that is. You just **check what is in your browser address bar** when you open that folder in the browser. No need to guess here :)

Comment: @Tristan Did you try it on Monday?  I'm having the same problem and it's a Monday and I've not found a solution yet...! :(

Comment: nope, sry, and I have no more access to this sharepoint.